# Go MongoDB driver not returning all documents

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm having some issues getting the fully expected results from a mongoDB query using the Golang driver.

I'm currently querying a collection with 5791 documents totaling around ~150MB. It seems that when the query gets a large amount of data as the result the cursor does not iterate over the complete set of documents expected.

For example:

Query returns 2290 documents instead of 5791 expected with no error and cursor iterates without error.

Is there anything in the FindOptions for the Collection.Find() perhaps to remove a byte size limit on the query results?

Here is the code I'm using:

```golang
func (db *Database) ExecuteQuery(coll string, query bson.M) ([]bson.M, error) {

    // Retrieve the appropriate database and collection to query on
    collection, ctx, cancel := database.getCollection(coll)
    defer cancel()

    cursor, err := collection.Find(ctx, query)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var res []bson.M
    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        //Create a value into which the single document can be decoded
        var elem bson.M
        err := cursor.Decode(&elem)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        res = append(res, elem)

    }

    cursor.Close(ctx)

    return res, nil
}
```

Comment: There is no size limit. Show your code

Comment: I'm thinking there is perhaps a cursor timeout that I need to set to false

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was when I implemented a method to get the a collection from the database I was getting the collection using `context.WithTimeout` which had a 10 second timeout. This basically capped the time I could execute a query using this context on this collection and so only the number of documents it could fit in that time period were returned.

The code below shows the change where the context is retrieved using `context.WithCancel` instead in order to let queries take as long as they want.

```golang
// getCollection retrieves the appropriate collection to query on and returns the context and context cancelling function tied to it.
func (db *Database) getCollection(coll string) (*mongo.Collection, context.Context, context.CancelFunc) {
    mongoDB := db.client.Database(db.Config.DatabaseName)
    collection := mongoDB.Collection(coll)

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    return collection, ctx, cancel
}
```